# OpenCV Contrast Preserving Decolorization

Tags: opencv, colors

Does OpenCV contain (or there is a contribute) a mature color to gray conversation (something like Contrast Preserving Decolorization) ?

Comment: First google result with "OpenCV Contrast Preserving Decolorization" is [OpenCV Decolorization](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/photo/doc/decolor.html) module

Comment: Oh! I saw it and I think it is the same cvtColor but in nice interface :D
I should try it... thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OpenCV [decolor](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/photo/doc/decolor.html) function of the *photo* contrib module.

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2\photo.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

    Mat1b grayscale;
    Mat3b color_boost;

    decolor(img, grayscale, color_boost);


    imshow("Original", img);
    imshow("Grayscale", grayscale);
    imshow("Color Boost", color_boost);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Original:

[image]

Grayscale:

[image]

Color Boost:

[image]